# Angular 2 Best Practices - Which HTML piece is qualified as component

Tags: angular, angular2-components, web-architecture

If I have one service returning multiple data points and these needs to be displayed in multiple html parts (in below case its three). What is the best way to organize & architect this ?

Kindly note that here Sections and Properties always displayed together.

There are three options, and I am bit confused between 1st and 2nd, which one to opt for.

1. Create three Components : TemplateComponent, SectionsComponent & PropertyComponent ?
2. Create two components : one Component for Templates and another component for Sections and Properties ?
3. Create one component : one component for all three sections.
4. ?

We are using Angular~2.0 with CLI.

**Sample Service Response**

> ```
> Template_A  
>      - Section 1
>        - Property a
>        - Property b 
>      - Section 2
>        - Property a
>        - Property b
> Template_B
>      - Section 1
>        - Property a
>        - Property b 
>      - Section 2
>        - Property a
>        - Property b
> ```

**Sample UI**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Base Component and Create as many child Components Required and Pass the Data to Child Components.

In you case, you will create three components.

1. TemplateComponent
2. SectionsComponent
3. PropertyComponent

   - **SectionsComponent** will be a child component of **TemplateComponent** which
     will receive *Sections Data* as input.
   - **PropertyComponent** will be a child of **SectionsComponent** which will receive *Properties Data* as input.

Refer to https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction for more info.